# Eclipse import into current project source code from another projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two separate projects in eclipse. However, one of the projects relies on java classes from the other project. Since I add the jar to the dependent project, I can run my standalones. However, when debugging I'd like to step into the source code for the other project. Is there a way to link these two projects together?

Comment: did you tried my answer below?

Comment: @mmc18. I went into Java Build Path but my project does not appear. I am trying to import the whole project now whereas before I only had a few source folders that were part of the project. Do you know why my project does not show up when selecting Add...? In project/package explorer, the project folder is missing an exclamation point. The projects that show up in Add... seem to have them.

Comment: Importing the whole project did the trick.

Comment: Both  projects have to be located in same workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a project which you want to add into source code of other project. then

```
Properties->JavaBuildPath->Add Projects
```

[image]